# Handling 307 and 301 in ConnectionRequest

Tags: codenameone

I am using ConnectionRequest and downloadImageToStorage to download an image from a web server. The webserver is returning a 307 with a location, that next url returns a 301 with another location, that location finally returns the actual image.

I defined a FailureCallback, but it is not getting called at all. All I can see is a message on the device screen that indicates the error and has a retry/cancel buttons.

Here is my code

```
FailureCallback<Image> failure = new FailureCallback<Image>() {
        public void onError(Object sender, Throwable err, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
            System.out.println(errorCode);
            if (errorCode == 307 || errorCode == 301) {
                System.out.println(sender.getClass().getName());
            }
        }
    };
    ConnectionRequest request = new ConnectionRequest();
    request.setUrl(url);
    request.setHttpMethod("GET");
    request.downloadImageToStorage("img_" + imgCount, (img) -> {
        SpanLabel t = new SpanLabel();
        t.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, img);
        myform.add(t);
    }, failure);

    ++imgCount;
```

How can I capture these errors so I can get the Location from the Response objects and call those with new ConnectionRequests?

Note that I can see the chain of error codes and locations when I use the debugger in Chrome to get the image that I am trying to load.

Thanks

Comment: The fact that fail isn't invoked might be a bug, I've asked Steve to look into that as he wrote that method and might have better insight into this.

Answer (score 1):

To capture error code and error message **setReadResponseForErrors** method should be called and override **handleErrorResponseCode** method of ConnectionRequest as shown in below code

```
request .setReadResponseForErrors(true);

@Override
            protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {

             Dialog.show("Message", " code "+ code+" msg "+message, "ok", null);
            }
```

Comment: That worked to get the code, but I also need to get the Location from the response header. I added a readHeaders override in the ConnectionRequest object, along with the handleErrorResponseCode, but the readHeaders method never gets called. How can I access the response headers?

Answer (score 0):

As Shai mentioned in his comment, there was a bug that caused 307 to be interpreted as an error response, rather than a redirect.  This should now be fixed in the latest, and this should cause your example to work.

There is also another bug which has not been fixed that prevents the onError() callback from being called when there is an error response code.  This will be fixed soon. In the mean time, your example should work (and the onError() will not be called) with 301 and 307 response codes.